# Multiple ImageButton OnClicklistener

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener, android-button

Im very new at this and I really searched for the answer.
I know this question will be very easy, but I really need help.

I have multiple `ImageButton`s, but dont know how I make different `OnClicklistener` for them.

This is my code, and I think something is missing here.

```
        ImageButton facebookButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButtonFacebook);
        ImageButton twitterButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButtonTwitter);

        facebookButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        twitterButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            }
        })

}

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch(v.getId()){
                case R.id.imageButtonFacebook:
                    Intent fb = new Intent (MainActivity.this, FacebookActivity.class);
                    startActivity(fb);
                    break;

                case R.id.imageButtonTwitter:
                    Intent tw  = new Intent (MainActivity.this, TwitterActivity.class);
                    startActivity(tw);
                    break;
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement `View.OnClickListener`:

```
public class MyClass extends Activity implements OnClickListener {...}
```

and then set the `OnClickListeners` like this:

```
facebookButton.setOnClickListener(this);
twitterButton.setOnClickListener(this);
```